Can DefaultAzureCredential work in SearchIndexerClient?
I am using Azure search indexer client. If I use AdminKey credential, everything works. But I want to use my user account (as this code will be used in an azure function and I want azure function's system identity to access the search indexer directly).
So I tried to use DefaultAzureCredential. But this gives me 403 error. From azure portal, I am an owner for the instance and I gave index reader and contributor roles to me as well. So is there a way to make it work?
var searchClient = new SearchIndexerClient(
    new Uri(searchEndpoint),
    new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
(await searchClient.GetIndexerStatusAsync(indexerName))

403 exception will be thrown here.

OK, worked it out. in the azure portal, I need to set API Access control to "Both". Before it was Key Only

Please post your sol as an answer.

Assign the appropriate role to the Azure Function’s system-assigned managed identity in Azure Cognitive Search. Set access control to Both to enable managed identity access. Check that Function app is set up to use DefaultAzureCredential, which will automatically pick up the managed identity for authentication.


Go to your Azure Function Under Settings, select Identity. System-assigned managed identity is enabled. If it’s not enabled, switch it on and save the changes.



After enabling, navigate to the Azure Cognitive Search instance in the Azure Portal. Select Access control (IAM) Click Add role assignment in the Role dropdown, select Search Index Data Contributor (this role grants permissions to manage the data in search indexes).


